# Does cycling tighten your butt?

Tags: fitness

I feel a little painful during the first few weeks of commute with bicycle. Just wondering that does it make my butt tighter and sexier?

Comment: Studies have shown that riding a bicycle everyday makes you more awesome than the general population http://triathlonhumor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/63116_10151198046048789_31184793_n.jpeg

Comment: The pain builds character.  (Don't believe it?  Just think of all the characters you encounter while cycling.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since cycling is primarily based on leg strength, which is derived from all parts of the leg (including the glutes or butt muscles), then yes.

Here's a great graphic that shows some of the muscles used during a typical pedal stroke:
[image: Muscle groups of the pedal stroke]

And basic anatomy tells us that the muscular system works together so it's virtually impossible to train one muscle exclusively without using others at least minimally.

Now, if you want to specifically target your butt, I'd recommend some supplementary exercises like [pelvic tilts/bridges](http://www.livestrong.com/article/29582-pelvic-bridging-exercise/) or [walking lunges](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/DBWalkingLunge.html).

Comment: That ***is*** a great graphic! Could you edit in a link to where you found it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not going to add the URL as that looks sloppy, but I will add it in this comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GPZZL.gif.

Comment: I actually meant a link that showed its original context. I'd be interested in reading the original article or blog post or whatever that it came from.

Comment: I can't find the original article I read about this, but a quick "cycling muscle usage" brings up a ton of references to this and similar diagrams. Most are obtained from power meter data combined with electrical muscle feedback.

Comment: Doing a "search by image" in google (http://www.google.com/imghp) with the URL of this graphic gives you the blog of a pretty famous MTB and strength coach: http://www.bikejames.com/strength/which-muscles-are-used-during-the-pedal-stroke/ (not sure if he is the original owner of that image though).

Comment: That blog post explains that the actual muscle usage is not nearly so simple, and the graphic may even be wrong, not just a summary. It includes a similar plot from actual measurements, which looks fairly different.

Comment: @Jefromi True, but as far as someone with limited knowledge of either anatomy or cycling is concerned, it's better than "uses your legs" and "ties all the anterior ligaments with, blah, blah, blah"!

Comment: @Aaron Doesn't mean it has to be misleading - an accurate graphic can still illustrate that cycling uses all those muscles, without perpetuating the oversimplification.

Answer (score 3):

> I feel a little painful...

If it pains because of seating on an improper seat then no, it will not tighten it.

If it pains due to miles of cycling together with standing pedaling uphill, then probably yes.

Comment: On the first point: More generally, improper fit - even if you have a saddle which can fit you properly, if its not set up correctly you get pain. Longer rides are also sore inducing at first for most people. Moving from a cruiser type seat to a road saddle changes the load bearing behavior for most people to more on the sit bones (with a corresponding change in riding position).